# import org.webrtc.AddIceObserver; can't find the location error

Tags: android, webrtc

Android app to use webrtc and try to import org.webrtc.AddIceObserver;

only "import org.webrtc.AddIceObserver;" has the error that can't find the location.
is it omitted from API package?

error:
*****WebRTC\app\src\main\java\com\example\webrtc\PeerConnectionClient.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
import org.webrtc.AddIceObserver;*****
^
symbol:   class AddIceObserver
location: package org.webrtc

Comment: Can you share your code for more details. Also, share which version of webrtc dependency you are using.

Comment: I have same issue, did you solve that?

Comment: I think, sample app not updated. Latest webrtc sdk, does not include AddIceObserver and also addIceCandidate method does not take AddIceObserver parameter any more. Just simply delete AddIceObserver.